# Sending Batch Request to Facebook Open Graph Beta

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to submit a batch request to add objects via Open Graph Beta to a user's Timeline but no matter what I do I get this:

`The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: egg.`

I *am* specifying an `egg` property though. My requests look like this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/?batch=[{'method':'POST','relative_url':'/me/my_namespace:find','egg':'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fmy_namespace%2Fog%2Fegg.php%3Ftypeid%3D-966','start_time':'1317439270','end_time':'1317439270'}]&access_token=<<snipped>>&method=post`

I am sending `egg` as a url-encoded reference string to a URL that contains my open graph data -- the URL does work if I send it not as a batch but since when setting up a user's Timeline I will in some cases have to post up to 1000 actions I am trying to speed things up by batching them.

I **was** able to successfully delete via a batch request.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sending the 'egg' as a param of the batch object, you need to format this like a query string and send it in the body param.

Also, relative_url should not begin with a '/'

Try posting this instead...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/batch?access_token=TOKEN&method=post&batch=
[
    {
        "method": "post",
        "relative_uri": "me/your_namespace:find",
        "body": "egg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fmy_namespace%2Fog%2Fegg.php%3Ftypeid%3D-966&start_time= 1317439270&end_time= 1317439270
    }
]
```

I've tested this and it works.

When Posting data to the batch API, the data must be formatted like a querysting and sent in the 'body' param as a string.

Comment: I'm getting a new error now "batch parameter must be a JSON array". My batch parameter is a properly formatted JSON array though: https://graph.facebook.com/batch?access_token=TOKEN&method=post&batch=[{"method":"POST","relative_uri":"me/my_namespace:find","body":"egg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fmy_namespace%2Fog%2Fegg.php%3Ftypeid%3D-966&start_time=1317439270&end_time=1317439270"},{"method":"POST","relative_uri":"me/my_namespace:find","body":"egg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fmy_namespace%2Fog%2Fegg.php%3Ftypeid%3D-968&start_time=1317438608&end_time=1317438608"}]

Comment: I have a facebook apps with two custom object types and two actions.  One action/object combo works fine.  The other gets the "does not specify any reference objects" error.  Every time.  I've tested both curl and javascript, same error either way.  I've copied the sample code from the developer app and get the same error.  So I hope someone posts a solution here!